# Firebase provider

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm creating an app that uses Firebase Authentication. I'd got provider's name with `.getProvider()` but Firebase was updated and now I'm using `FirebaseAuth` and `FirebaseUser` and I don't know how to get that name if I have login buttons (Google, Facebook, Twitter and email & password) in the same Activity.

Answer (score 3):

Problem can be solved by using code -

```
FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();    
FirebaseUser user =mAuth.getCurrentUsers();    
String provider = user.getProviders().get(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the provider id of the currently logged in user. It should look similar to the code snippet below:

```
    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Provider ID: " + user.getProviderId());
            }
        }
    };
```

Here's the Firebase class reference documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser.html#getProviderId()